# Error running npm update: No compatible version found: fsevents

Tags: node.js, npm, karma-runner

I am trying to setup a new build server running Angular Karma and I am having issues.

When I run npm update I get the following error:

```
381 error notarget No compatible version found: fsevents@'pipobscure/fsevents#7dcdf9fa3f8956610fd6f69f72c67bace2de7138'
381 error notarget Valid install targets:
381 error notarget ["0.1.1","0.1.3","0.1.4","0.1.5","0.1.6","0.2.0","0.3.0"]
381 error notarget
381 error notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
381 error notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
381 error notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
382 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
383 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "update"
384 error cwd ****
385 error node -v v0.10.26
386 error npm -v 1.4.3
387 error code ETARGET
388 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

The dependencies in my package.json looks like this:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "karma": "~0.12.23",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.14",
    "karma-requirejs": "~0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.4"
  }
```

I am running npm v1.4.3 and node v0.10.26

When I run this on my dev machine, I don't get this error, so something must be different, but I'm not sure what! I do get a warning on my dev machine, but that's it.

It seems to be the karma package that at some point depends on fsevents, but I can't see which of the dependencies that is.

Answer (score 1):

Update your npm

```
npm install -g npm
```

This was a bug in an earlier version of npm: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4984

You may get warnings when you update. Run the update one more time and you should see a clean npm install.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing your karma module separately and globally (`npm -g`).

OR

if the problem still persists, try installing it from a mirror:

`sudo npm install --registry http://registry.npmjs.eu -g karma`